# What is the equivalent of the SQL Server SSMS generate script without data in MySQL 8.X?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I would like a script file(.sql) of the metadata from a MySQL Database?

Comment: as phrased, this question can only be well answered by someone familiar with both products.  if you describe in detail what an "SSMS generate script" does or what you want, then it becomes better answerable by someone knowing only mysql

Answer (score 0):

[mysqldump --no-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)

Read the documentation for more details.